# Micro-finance data set

Tags: finance, economics

I am looking for the data sets on micro-finance institutions per country. I have tried to find it in the World Banks data base but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MIX Market (Micro-finance Information Exchange). Here's the link to the [dataset page](https://www.themix.org/mixmarket/datasets). Yes, you can also get information per country as well; check this [page](http://www.themix.org/mixmarket/countries-regions). The idea of MIX Market was to serve as the Bloomberg of Micro-finance data.